# Get collection of elements from JSON, when elements are multiple levels below from parent struct

Tags: json, swift

So I have a JSON File with following structure:

```
public struct main: Decodable {
    let features: [Features]
}
struct Features: Decodable{
    let something: String
    let properties: [Properties]
}
struct Properties: Decodable{
    let title: String
}
```

With my JSON Decoder Function I have no problems to get Information from Features.something, but I'm struggling to find out, **how could I get to the title of Properties.**

```
getJSON(urlString: urlString) { (results: main?) in
    if let result = results {
        for result in results.features {
            print(result.something)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would have to iterate through the array of properties. Similar to how you are iterating through features.

Comment: Loop again: `for feature in results.features { print("Feature something: \(feature.something) for property in feature.properties { print("Property title: \(property.title) } }`